# Generar Nombre de Usuario apartir de nombre y apellido

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente código donde ingreso a un usuario, pero quiero validar si el `username` que le estoy asignando al usuario ya existe y si es asi que le agrege agrega un numero al `username` Ejemplo: JPerez, JPerez1, JPerez2.

```
 // Separamos los Nombres
    list($pri_nombre, $seg_nombre) = explode(" ", $nombre);
    // Separamos los Apellidos
    list($pri_apellido, $seg_apellido) = explode(" ", $apellido);

    // QUITAMOS LOS ESPACIOS EN BLANCO, EJEMPLO DE APELLIDO: DEL  CAMPO
    $pri_nombre   = preg_replace('/[ <>\'\"]/', '', $pri_nombre);
    $seg_nombre   = preg_replace('/[ <>\'\"]/', '', $seg_nombre);
    $pri_apellido = preg_replace('/[ <>\'\"]/', '', $pri_apellido);
    $seg_apellido = preg_replace('/[ <>\'\"]/', '', $seg_apellido);

    // Ticket de Condicion
    $username_encontrado = FALSE;

    $largo_nombre = strlen($pri_nombre); //largo del nombre
    $j            = 1; //INDICA LA CANTIDAD DE CARACTERES A EXTRAER DEL NOMBRE

    $username = cortar_string(substr($pri_nombre, 0, $j) . $pri_apellido, 12);
    while (!$username_encontrado) {

        $ver_username = "SELECT Codigo FROM personal where NomUser = '$username'";
        $resultt      = mysqli_query($conn, $ver_username);

        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($resultt);
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            $username_encontrado = FALSE;
            // Aqui agregar el username se repite
        } else {
            $username_encontrado = TRUE;
        }

    }
```

Como seria el código para modificar el `$username` si me encuentra uno igual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo crear una variable $i que vaya llevando la secuencia de los números que usaras como sufijos en los nombre, cada vez que se evalúe el if y el usuario ya exista, esta variable se incrementa en 1, se concatena con el nombre del usuario que inicialmente había y se vuelve a hacer la consulta, así sucesivamente hasta encontrar un usuario JPerez.$i disponible:

```
// Separamos los Nombres
    list($pri_nombre, $seg_nombre) = explode(" ", $nombre);
    // Separamos los Apellidos
    list($pri_apellido, $seg_apellido) = explode(" ", $apellido);

    // QUITAMOS LOS ESPACIOS EN BLANCO, EJEMPLO DE APELLIDO: DEL  CAMPO
    $pri_nombre   = preg_replace('/[ <>\'\"]/', '', $pri_nombre);
    $seg_nombre   = preg_replace('/[ <>\'\"]/', '', $seg_nombre);
    $pri_apellido = preg_replace('/[ <>\'\"]/', '', $pri_apellido);
    $seg_apellido = preg_replace('/[ <>\'\"]/', '', $seg_apellido);

    // Ticket de Condicion
    $username_encontrado = FALSE;

    $largo_nombre = strlen($pri_nombre); //largo del nombre
    $j            = 1; //INDICA LA CANTIDAD DE CARACTERES A EXTRAER DEL NOMBRE

    $username = cortar_string(substr($pri_nombre, 0, $j) . $pri_apellido, 12);

        $i = 0;//Sufijo numero del username
        $username_inicial = $username;
    $username_encontrado = FALSE;
    while (!$username_encontrado) {

        $ver_username = "SELECT * FROM personal WHERE NomUser = '$username'";
        $resultt      = mysqli_query($conn, $ver_username);

        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($resultt);
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            $username_encontrado = FALSE;
            // Aqui agregar el username se repite
                    ++$i;//Se incrementa en uno
                    $username = $username_inicial.$i;//Se agrega al nombre de usuario original

        } else {
            $username_encontrado = TRUE;
        }

    }

var_dump($username_encontrado);
var_dump($username);
```

Esa opción te funcionaria, sin embargo me parece algo ineficiente, considerando todas las consultas que tienes que hacer a la base de datos, si por ejemplo, en la base de datos existe desde JPerez, JPerez1...hasta Jperez10, entonces al ir en secuencia solo hasta la consulta No. 12 conseguiría un nombre de usuario disponible. Por ello, como segunda alternativa te propongo esto (aunque hace uso de PDO y no de mysqli):

La ventaja de esta opcion es que previene inyecciones de SQL, ten cuidado cuando insertas variables directamente en el SQL con mysqli_query, y en segundo lugar, no hace consultas repetidas hasta conseguir un usuario valido. Basicamente, hace la primera consulta para verificar si el usuario existe. Si existe, hace un segunda consulta donde extrae todos los usuarios que comienzan por ese nombre de usuario (asi obtiene todos los sufijos asignados). Almacena todos los usuarios ocupados en un array, el cual usa como referencia para comparar si los nuevos usuarios calculados estan o no disponibles.

Adicionalmente la variable $i no inicia desde cero, sino desde el numero siguiente a la cantidad de usernames ocupados con ese nombre, así no tenemos que recorrer todo desde el principio, aunque esto no garantiza que habrá solo una iteracion, pero si las reduce, puede que exista Jperez6, pero el resultado del count sea mejor que 6 porque JPerez5 haya sido borrado. Espero se entienda:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nombreBD', "root", "");
// Separamos los Nombres
list($pri_nombre, $seg_nombre) = explode(" ", $nombre);
// Separamos los Apellidos
list($pri_apellido, $seg_apellido) = explode(" ", $apellido);

// QUITAMOS LOS ESPACIOS EN BLANCO, EJEMPLO DE APELLIDO: DEL  CAMPO
$pri_nombre   = preg_replace('/[ <>\'\"]/', '', $pri_nombre);
$seg_nombre   = preg_replace('/[ <>\'\"]/', '', $seg_nombre);
$pri_apellido = preg_replace('/[ <>\'\"]/', '', $pri_apellido);
$seg_apellido = preg_replace('/[ <>\'\"]/', '', $seg_apellido);

// Ticket de Condicion
$username_encontrado = FALSE;

$largo_nombre = strlen($pri_nombre); //largo del nombre
$j            = 1; //INDICA LA CANTIDAD DE CARACTERES A EXTRAER DEL NOMBRE

$username = cortar_string(substr($pri_nombre, 0, $j) . $pri_apellido, 12);

$username_inicial = $username;
$username_encontrado = FALSE;

$sql_1 = "SELECT username FROM personal WHERE NomUser = :usr";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql_1);
$query->execute(array(':usr' => $username));

if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
    $sql_2 = "SELECT username FROM personal WHERE NomUser LIKE :usr";
    $query_2 = $conn->prepare($sql_2);
    $query_2->execute(array(':usr' => "{$username}%"));
    $resultado = $query_2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);//Obtiene array con usuarios ocupados

    $i = $query_2->rowCount();//Sufijo numero del username
    while (!$username_encontrado) {
        ++$i;
        $username = $username_inicial.$i;
        if (in_array($username, $resultado)) {
                $username_encontrado = FALSE;
        } else {
                $username_encontrado = TRUE;
        }
   }
    } else {
    $username_encontrado = TRUE;
}

echo $username;
?>
```

Espero te funcione, quedo atento.